# Why can't I return the string person into main? It gives me a error saying that the string "person" is not in the context even though I returned it?

Tags: c#

It gives me this error even though the function should have returned the value person? Is it because I can't return strings? if that's so, then is there a way around it?

> main.cs(7,23): error CS0103: The name `person' does not exist in the current context.

```
class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) 
  {
    CreateName();
    Console.WriteLine(person);
  }
  static string CreateName(){
    Console.Write("Enter a name: ");
    string person = Console.ReadLine(); 
    return person;
  }
}
```

Comment: `string person = CreateName(); Console.WriteLine(person);`

Comment: I would suggest a little read on [what are scopes of variables](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c-sharp/) to get a better understanding on when a variable is alive and when and where it can be accessed from. You have method level scopes.. not class level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *value* is indeed returned from the method.  But the variable you're looking for was declared only within that method and exists only within that method.

The returned value is then ignored:

```
CreateName();
```

You can store that value in its own variable:

```
var result = CreateName();
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Or just use it directly for the purpose you want:

```
Console.WriteLine(CreateName());
```

Another option might be to use a class-level member instead of local variables.  For example:

```
class MainClass
{
    private static string person;

    public static void Main (string[] args) 
    {
        CreateName();
        Console.WriteLine(person);
    }

    static void CreateName()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter a name: ");
        person = Console.ReadLine(); 
    }
}
```

In this case the methods are both using the same variable that's in a scope shared by both methods, so nothing needs to be returned or re-stored in a new local variable.

There are a variety of options for passing data around your application.  But "variables" aren't passed around or returned, they exist only within the scope in which they're declared.

Answer (score 1):

your not catching the call. you need to do this

```
var person = CreateName();
```